# Broadcast event when scripts were loaded in lightning down the hierarchy

Tags: lightning-events

If I want to broadcast event when scripts were loaded in lightning down the hierarchy what should I do?

Should I use the `APPLICATION` type event or are there other ways to do that?

For example, here I would like to initialize `Inner.cmp` and everything inside it after the libraries will be loaded:

```
<aura:component description="Outer">
    <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', $Resource.jqueryLib, $Resource.d3Lib)}"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.broadcastEvent}" />
    <c:Inner/>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Are you loading the different script in all the components? and please do share the code flow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `aura:method`  and call the `Inner.cmp` doInit from the parent component's `afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.broadcastEvent"}`.

[>> Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_method.htm)